# Compiled vs Interpreted: To Let or Not To Let

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghci, interpretation

Why does the Haskell interpreter (GHCI 7.10.3) need function definitions to be in a let expression, but the Haskell compiler (GHC 7.10.3) throws a parser error if a function definition is within a let expression?

I'm working through "[Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out)!" Baby's first function is doubleMe:
    doubleMe x = x + x

Why does the interpreter accept this definition if it is within a let expression and otherwise throw a parse error on input '='? Meanwhile, if I'm compiling the same function from a file, why does GHC throw a parse error if the function definition is within a let expression and compiles the definition if it is not within a let expression? Coming from a Lisp background, I'm surprised that interactive Haskell and file loading and compilation Haskell treats these definitions differently.

Comment: It's a convention. If GHCi worked exactly as writing in a .hs file, writing `1+1` would be an error, as well as `print (2,3)`. Instead, GCHi chose to use a little magic so to accept both these expressions and `let` definitions. About why `x=1` without let is rejected -- I don't think there's a clear answer to that except "it would require more magic".

Comment: Right. FWIW, [IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell) allows mixing both styles.

Comment: The newest version of GHCi (8.0.1) accepts `doubleMe x = x + x`. Enough people like you complained that they added a special case for this. :)

Comment: This is a fundamental difference I now appreciate between Haskell and Lisp: interactive access to the compiler via a command prompt vs interactive access to the language itself via a REPL, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern Lisp implementations compile to native code, often by default even when code is entered at the prompt. Lisp's prompt isn't just a place to enter commands, it's a place to interact with the language because the entire language is made available by the Read-Evaluate-Print Loop. This means that Lisp reads the text into symbolic expressions, which it then evaluates, printing any print output and any returned values. For example,

```
? (defun a-fun () nil)
A-FUN
? (compiled-function-p #'a-fun)
T
```

[Compiled-Function-P](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cmpd_f.htm)
[Clozure Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clozure_CL#Technology)

With Lisp, code you can enter into the Lisp image by compiling and loading a file you can also enter into the Lisp image by typing it out at the REPL. So it turns out I was surprised because I was expecting the GHCi prompt to be a REPL, but as [@Alec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072788/alec) describes it's not because it doesn't read text into Haskell expressions that it would then evaluate, as Lisp does. As [@dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) says, the issue isn't about compilation versus interpretation. The issue is that GHCi's prompt offers limited interaction with a Haskell compiler, rather than interaction with Haskell itself as Lisp's REPL does.

Answer (score 4):

The reasoning behind this is that GHCi (in 7.10.3) expects at the prompt only

- [commands](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html) (type in `:h` to list the commands available)
- [declarations](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-decls) (things like `data`, `type`, `newtype`, `class`, `instance`, `deriving`, and `foreign` but *not* a regular definition)
- [imports](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-import-decl)
- [expressions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) (things like `1+1` or `let x = 3 in x*x`)
- [I/O Actions / `do` statments](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#actions-at-prompt) (things like `print "hi"` or `x <- getLine` **OR** `let doubleMe x = x + x`)

If this seems surprising to you, remember that the evaluation of Lisp and Haskell is very different - Lisp just gets interpretted, while Haskell is being compiled.

As you can tell, top-level definitions are not part of this list. Thankfully this got fixed in GHCi 8.0.1, which now supports raw top-level function declarations. The following works (in 8.0.1):

```
ghci> doubleMe x = x + x
ghci> doubleMe 1
2
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with compilation and interpretation. Lots of Lisp actually is compiled, I believe, although I think Scheme may be the only Lisp that's really designed for good compilation.

Comment: I suspect the real motivation for not including this functionality in early versions of ghci is the surprising behavior of e.g. `maybeDoubleMe Nothing = Nothing\nmaybeDoubleMe (Just x) = Just (x+x)` in ghci compared to in a file.

Answer (score 3):

The GHCi interpreter command line treats its input as if it were in a `do` clause. So you can type this:

```
:module + System.Random
v <- getStdRandom $ randomR (1,10)
```

Apart from the `:module` directive this is exactly how it would be in a `do` clause.

Likewise you can write

```
let f x = 2 * x
```

because that is how it would be in a `do` clause.